# Distribution of integral of Brownian bridge

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let us consider a process $\{X(t);t\in[0,1]\}$. Let us define $X(t)=\int_0^tg(u)dB(u)$ where $g$ is a deterministic function and $B$ is Brownian **bridge** process.

Then what will be the mean and variance function of $X(t)$?

If we assume $B$ to be a Brownian **motion** the mean function is zero and variance function (from Eto's isometry), we can get
$$V(X(t))=\int_0^tg^2(u)du.$$

Stuck in the case of Brownian bridge.

Comment: **An approach**: Represent $B(u)$ as $W(u)-uW(1)$, $0\le u\le 1$, where $W$ is a Brownian motion.

Comment: @JohnDawkins...I tried in this approach, it is giving a variance function which cann't be expressed as explicit and simple form as Brownian motion.

Comment: The explicit expression I get is $\int_0^t [g(u)]^2\,du-[\int_0^t g(u)\,du]^2$.